# functions in require("x.php") works in some of the code, but cannot be called in the next?

Tags: php, variables, loops, global-variables, require

I have this code `

```
        require("db_connect.php");

        function xx()
        {

        $conn = db_connect(); //here it works
        (...)

        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');      
        if(time() <= $x[0]){
            (...)
            }else
        {

            (...)                   
            for ($x = 0; $x < count($GLOBALS['car_park']); $x++)
            {

            $conn = db_connect(); //here i get :Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
            $res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM x WHERE owner='x' AND x='0' ORDER BY id DESC ");
            if (!$res) {
                //die(msg(0,"Could not execute query"));
            }   

            }

        }


}
```

`

I have cut out all echo's and some other loops and such, but other then that I think the code is the same. I seem to hit this problem with global variable scope all the time. I think the variable is global and always set, the code stops working and I figure out after lots of hassle that the variable that i thought was global suddenly is gone.. Very annoying..

db_connect function:

```
function db_connect() {
   $result = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
     if (!$result) {
       die(msg(0,"Could not connect to database server"));
   } else { 
     return $result; 
  }
}
```

Ok. I tried this code before the db_connect:

```
if (isset ($conn)){
                echo "set"; 
                }
            else {
                echo "unset"; 
                }
```

and it shows up set. Why do I get: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) then??

Answer (score 4):

You shouln't need to connect to the database for every call, one $conn = db_connect(); is enough.

Can we have a look at the `db_connect()` function.

Comment: postet the db_connect function, but I don't think thats the problem